# Select a especific DB on symfony login action in multi-tenant SaaS DB

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, multi-tenant, saas

My application is a SaaS multi-client app. Each client has a different DB. Through a service, the client is redirected to a DB or another one on each request.

My problem is that when login on Symfony, the client search for data on the original DB (the one set in `parameters.yml`) and not the client specific DB.

I attempted to create a service to listen on the `security.interactive_login`event to change the connection settings but it always keep on searching on the `parameters.yml` DB.

Is it possible to redirect to a determinate DB in the login action? (not the DB defined on `parameters.yml`)

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/